# Youtube embed not working

Tags: html, iframe

Youtube embed code is not working, How can fix this?

https://fiddle.jshell.net/prabu0301/pLwz2bnx/3/

Comment: Take a look at your browser's debugging console.  What does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you were using a ***wrong*** `src` for the `<iframe>`. You should use

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/Foayrk4V5b4?&autoplay=1
```

instead of

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/Foayrk4V5b4?&autoplay=1
```

The `https://` was the problem.

```css
/* --- RESPONSIVE VIDEO --- */

.embed-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16/9 ratio */
  padding-top: 30px;
  /* IE6 workaround*/
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.embed-container iframe,
.embed-container object,
.embed-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}


/* --- This isn't needed, but helps demonstrate the "responsiveness" --- */

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Scale Me - Responsive Video</h1>

  <div class="embed-container">
    <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Foayrk4V5b4?&autoplay=1"></iframe>


  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? Why not?